# Asp test if alphabetic

Tags: asp-classic, sql-like

I am new in asp becouse I usaly use aspx

I use function that should loop through all chars of string and delete all chars that are not numbers or alphabet chars. The line

```
If sChar Like "[0-9A-Za-z]" Then
```

return error: Sub or Function not defined

```
MM_folder_vpisan = "fdvddvsd.-,čšž"

For lCtr = 1 To Len(MM_folder_vpisan)
     sChar = Mid(MM_folder_vpisan, lCtr, 1)
     If sChar Like "[0-9A-Za-z]" Then
         sAns = sAns & sChar
     End If    
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I believe is an improved version of this code :

```
Set objRegExp = New RegExp
objRegExp.Pattern = "[^0-9A-Z]" 'we'll ignorecase so no need for a-z
objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp.Global = True
sAns = objRegExp.replace(MM_folder_vpisan, "") ' replace all that is not 0-9 or A-Z
Set objRegExp = nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this regular expression command: (see the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx#regexnet_topic11))

```
String newText = Regex.Replace(inputString, pattern, replacementText);
```

where

- `inputString` is the string you are removing characters from.
- `pattern` is the regex, `"\w"`. (This is a Metacharacter that matches any of `[0-9a-zA-Z]`)
- `replacementText` is what you replace it with. To delete, you would simply put a blank string.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I agree regular expressions should be able to do this but the question is classic ASP so presumably will need the [VBScript RegExp Object](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html)

Comment: Additionally, `\w` matches `_`.